# Understanding the CM type of a CM-field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/F$ be a CM-field with complex conjugation $c$ as the nontrivial element of $\mathrm{Gal}(K/F)$ Let $I_K$ be the set of embeddings $\sigma: K \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Let $\Sigma$ be a fixed CM-type.

Let $p$ be an odd prime number that is unramifed in $K$ and every place in $F$ above  $p$ splits completely in $K$.

Let $K^{nc}$ be the normal closure (i.e. Galois closure) of $K$ in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

**My question is how to understand the following paragraph** from [this paper of Ming-Lun Hsieh](http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/%7Emlhsieh/research/IMCCM.pdf) (page 10, section 1.5):

> To every $\sigma \in I_K$, we can attach an idempotent $e_{\sigma} \in \mathcal{O}_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathcal{O}_{K^{nc}} \,$ such that $ae_{\sigma} = \sigma(a) e_{\sigma}$ for $a \in \mathcal{O}_K$ and
> $$
> \mathcal{O}_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathcal{O}_{K^{nc}} = \bigoplus_{\sigma \in I_K} \mathcal{O}_{K^{nc}} \cdot e_{\sigma}.  \quad\quad (\star)
> $$
> Let $e^{+} := \sum_{\sigma \in \Sigma} e_{\sigma}$. If $M$ is an $\mathcal{O}_K$-module, we put $M_p = M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $M_{\Sigma} := e^{+}(M_p)$. ....

**Confusion 1**: Where does this direct sum decomposition $(\star)$ come from? How to understand this?

*My attempts*: If we choose an integral basis $\{ \omega_1, \ldots, \omega_n \}$ of $\mathcal{O}_K$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, then we have
$$
\mathcal{O}_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathcal{O}_{K^{nc}} = (\mathbb{Z}\omega_1 \oplus  \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z} \omega_n) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathcal{O}_{K^{nc}} = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n} \mathcal{O}_{K^{nc}}  \cdot \omega_i \quad\quad (\dagger)
$$
But the problem is:

- This involves taking a basis, which is not canonical.
- Though indeed the numbers match ($\#I_K = n$), **how does this integral basis $\omega_i$ corresponds to the embeddings $\sigma \in I_K$**? Moreover, as one defines a CM-type $\Sigma$, how can we **canonically** pick out half of the basis element under this mysterious correspondence $\omega_i \leftrightarrow \sigma_i$? [I'm guessing that we can write the basis in the form of $\alpha_i \beta_j$, where $\alpha_i$ is an integral basis of $F$ and $\beta_i$ is some kind of "*normal basis*" of $\mathcal{O}_K / \mathcal{O}_F$. But I cannot make it precise.]
- Anyway, **what are these idempotents $e_{\sigma}$??** [A direct sum decomposition $(\dagger)$ corresponds to idempotents in the $\mathrm{End}$ ring. BUT not the original ring! So I am confused.]

**Confusion 2**: What is the $e^{+}(M_p)$?

*My thoughts*: It seem that **via some correspondence** that I do not know, we can regard $e^{+} \in \mathcal{O}_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathcal{O}_{K^{nc}}$ as some kind of **projection operator** acting on $M_p$. As I have no idea on "**Confusion 1**", this confused me as well.

---

More detailed setup:

**CM-fields**: This means that $K/F/\mathbb{Q}$ is a tower of field extensions of finite degree, with $F/\mathbb{Q}$ a totally real field (i.e. all its embeddings are real: $\sigma: F \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ has image in $\mathbb{R}$) and $K/F$ is a quadratic extension with $K/\mathbb{Q}$ totally imaginary (i.e. all its embeddings are complex ones: $\tau: F \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with image properly containing $\mathbb{R}$).

> Example: Imaginary quadratic extensions $K$ over $F:= \mathbb{Q}$.

**CM-types**: Based on my naiive understanding, we can decompose the set $I_K$ into a disjoint union $ I_K = \Sigma \sqcup c\Sigma $. Then $\Sigma$ is called a **CM-type** of $K/F$.

---

Thank you so much for commenting and answering!

Comment: This looks a bit suspicious – the stated decomposition seems to imply in particular that $O_{K} \otimes O_{K^{nc}}$ is a smooth algebra over $O_{K^{nc}}$. By flat descent, it means that $O_K$ is smooth over $\mathbb{Z}$ ie that $K$ is ramified nowhere, so $K=\mathbb{Q}$…

Comment: However, this problem disappears if you forget the “integral” part. Consider the matrix of a primitive element $\alpha$ of $K/\mathbb{Q}$ acting as a $\mathbb{Q}$-endomorphism of $K$. It is similar to the diagonal matrix $(\sigma(\alpha))_{\sigma}$, where $\sigma$ runs through the embeddings $K \rightarrow K^{nc}$. In other words, there’s a decomposition $K \otimes K^{nc} \cong Ke_{\sigma}$, where multiplication by $\alpha$ acts on the $\sigma$ factor by $te_{\sigma} \longmapsto (\sigma(\alpha)t) \cdot e_{\sigma}$.

Comment: @Aphelli Thank you for your reply and thank you for your hint!